# send email using exchange web server with body contains URL

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to send the email using exchange web service c#. It works fine if body contains normal text. But the body contains the URL like below is not working. it is sending the mail, but URL is not coming in the receipt end.

url contains <  >

http://localhost:52122/Home?Function=ABC&Parameter1=12345

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please show the body of email with url

Comment: body of the url , which i am sending to the exchange service to send mail is    "<http://localhost:52122/Home?Function=ABC&Parameter1=12345>"

Comment: Add just http://localhost:52122/Home?Function=ABC&Parameter1=12345. You could try to add <a> href="http://localhost:52122/Home?Function=ABC&Parameter1=12345">Your link</a> but as body in emal is plain text it would not render html link. Some modern mail clients might have that function

Comment: is your issue resolve?

Answer (score 0):

replace the body content with this code

```
string Url = "localhost:52122/Home?Function=ABC&Parameter1=12345";
string EmailBody = @"Email Body </br> please " + String.Format("<a href='{0}'>Click here</a>", Url);
```